# Symfony :my entity does not read my search method which is located into my repository

Tags: php

I am trying to manipulate the search part of my project but this error appear when I search for anything
here is my entity code :
I declared the repository in my entity

```
 /**
 * Event
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Event\EventBundle\Repository\EventRepository")

* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Event
{//code....
}
```

into my repository I put my query :

```
class EventRepository extends EntityRepository
{

public function recherche($chaine)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u')// ON MET PAS FROM PSQON EST DEJA DANS L'EVENT
        ->where('u.titre_even like :chaine')
        //->andWhere('u.disponible=1')

        ->orderBy('u.id')
        ->setParameter('chaine', $chaine);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
}
```

In my colroller I declared two functions :

```
   public function rechercheAction(){
$form = $this->createForm(new RechercheType());
    return $this->render('EventBundle:Event:recherche.html.twig',    array('form' => $form->createView()));

}


public function rechercheTraitementAction()
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new RechercheType());

    //vérifier q c b1 une methode post
    if ($this->get('request')->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        //récuperer les données pour les utiliser dans des requetes par la suite en fonction de la saisie
        $form->bind($this->get('request'));

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        //afficher le mot qu'on a saisie
        // echo $form['recherche']->getData();

        $entities = $em->getRepository('EventBundle:Event')->recherche($form['recherche']->getData());

    }else {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('event n\'existe pas.');
    }

    return $this->render('EventBundle:Event:index.html.twig', array('entities' => $entities));

}
```

this is my rooting of search:

```
event_recherche:
    path:     /recherche
    defaults: { _controller: "EventBundle:Event:rechercheTraitement" }
```

this is the erreur that I get :

Undefined method 'recherche'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!

please I need your helps guys !

Comment: You are mixing your language with French. And that makes me understand a little

Comment: problem solved thanks for ur help :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove second @ORM\Entity annotation from entity, it overrides first one, that is why your repository class is not used

Comment: how can I think you ! I'm so excited ! u solved my problem :D

Comment: sorry ! but I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting this line wrong `->where('u.titre_even like :chaine')` it should be `->where('u.titre_even like $chaine')`